# Persist user name and page name to database

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc

I have a small `JSF` application and the scope of the pages are `request`. I would like to have a method in my JSF's managed bean for logging `user_id` and `page name` to database. When I added this method to the constructor of bean, details are getting logged for every method is being called due to the fact that scope of the page is `request`.

What is the best way to log the above details only once when user first access the pages after logging into my application? Idea is which all pages user visited for each logging.
What is the best way to achieve this?

My JSF version is 1.1.

Thanks

Comment: I roughly understand what you are trying to ask... what do you mean with "scope of pages", there is scope for Managed Beans but... pages? ... and what method are you talking about? can you post some code??

Comment: I meant by scope of pages is whether page's scope is request, session, application etc which is defined in `faces-config.xml`. I have a custom method like `dbbean.getpagedetails(bean.getUserId(), this.getClass().getName().toString());`. I would like to have this in my bean, however when I added this method in constructor of the bean, it gets invoked for every action of the page. I believe this is because scope is `request`. If scope was s`ession` it would invoke only once. So being the scope is `request` which is the best place to add this method in bean? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to the bean and invoke it from the page when the page is loaded. For example

add this into the page:

```
<h:outputText value="#{fooBean.logUser}"/>
```

bean method:

```
public void logUser(){
    //log user and page
}
```

This way the method is only invoked once the page is loaded. If you get a method not found 
error, then another option is to use a hidden form hack. For example:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('formId:buttonId').click()">
    <h:form id="formId" style="display: none;">
        <h:commandButton id="buttonId" value="submit" action="#{fooBean.logUser()}" />
    </h:form>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: A method can be added to `<h:outputText`? If so how could I do this? Because when I tried `<h:outputText value="#{fooBean.logUser}"/>`, I am getting `logUser` `property` not found error. Thanks

Comment: @Polappan The JSF by default will be expecting a getter method in a <h:outputText> tag, you have to put the full qualified name of the method. fooBean.logUser() and not fooBean.logUser.

Comment: I believe `foobean.logUser()` may not work in JSF 1.1. When I tried I am getting `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: foobean.logUser() at com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.OutputTextTag.doStartTag(OutputTextTag.java:165)`. Thanks

Comment: @Polappan I'm sorry I haven't noticed your JSF version is 1.1, in 2.0 this works fine. However, this is not the best way to invoke a method, I'm sure there are several ways to call a method in the bean.

Comment: If I use this in `body` `onLoad`, then I guess page would go into some kind of loop when user does any other stuff in the page as page gets re-loaded again and again!

Comment: @Polappan Yes you are right, the loops will occur on navigation. These are the shortcomings of using this technique. However, it seems difficult to accomplish this in JSF 1.1,  unless you use a different scope such as view or session.

Comment: I believe when user does any kind of navigation or open a `pop up` window and return back, body `onLoad` will gets invoked. Thanks.

Comment: @Polappan Is it possible for you to use Ajax request?

Comment: Hmm need to think in that perspective now. Any limitations with JSF 1.1 with using Ajax?. Thanks.

Comment: @Polappan I dont think that JSF 1.1 has built-in support for Ajax. However, what I know is that JSF from its beginning was often used with Ajax everywhere. In JSF 1.x the ajax support needs to be added through javascript. You should not face any problem implementing ajax with jsf as they work perfectly together.

Comment: @Polappan I'm really not sure about how ajax and JSF 1.x would integrate together, you need to test and research in that area.

Comment: Thanks I will do some research into this. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to log into a database table all accesses of all users to the different pages of your site but, avoiding logging post-backs, right? (a post-back happens when a user performs an action in one of your pages and the URL that receives the action is the same than the one from where the action was launched - it's very common in JSF, specially on versions prior to 2.x)

So, basically, what you need is to recognize when a post-back happens and avoid logging under that condition. The [ResponseStateManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/render/ResponseStateManager.html) will provide you with a `isPostback(...)` method that returns `true` when processing post-back requests:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ResponseStateManager rsm = context.getRenderKit().getResponseStateManager();
if (!rsm.isPostback(context)) {
   // do whatever you need here
}
```

By the way, I wouldn't recommend to put that code in the bean constructor at all as different JSF implementations may perform some bean lifecycle management tasks right after invoking the bean's constructor. If you think that logic should be part of the "bean initialization process" I suggest putting that code in a separate public method annotated with a [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation.

However, if you want that logic to be run in every single access to the given pages, using a managed bean will force you to either copy & paste that logic in every bean or define an abstract/base class with that logic and make all your beans extend that one. I like to keep all my managed beans as close as possible to the POJO concept so, as an alternative, I would consider implementing the same logic but using a [PhaseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) tied to the `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase. It will give you a *under-the-hood* (much cleaner) and versatile approach: if some day you want to log ***actions*** instead of ***renders*** then you tie your listener to the `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase, etc.

P.D.: I hope you are using some kind of cache or '*batching*' technique to log those records to your database, otherwise you will have a noticeable performance impact when too many users are surfing your site. Also, in my own opinion, you should update your JSF version to, at least, 1.2, and you'll avoid some annoying bugs or unexpected behaviour...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. As I am using JSF 1.1, I wouldn't be able to use `@PostConstruct` annotations. Being this is the case what is the best way to invoke a method from my JSF page if I do not add `loguser()` method in `constructor` of bean? Thanks.

Comment: please, note that I don't know exactly how you obtain the reference to that `dbbean`. If your are not able to switch to JSF 1.2 and you are injecting `dbbean` into the consumer you could perform that task in the `setDBBean` method of the consumer (but I wouldn't recommend it at all). You could obtain a reference to that bean in some other way (from the session, servlet context, spring), then I'd recommend to use the `PhaseListener` approach.

Comment: I cannot find a method called rsm.isPostBack(context)) as I was testing postBack approach. Thanks.

Comment: alright, there was typo in my answer as the B in `isPostBack` is lower case - so it's `isPostback(context)`, did you check the API link in my answer? the method exists, it's public and me myself has used it a lot before.

Comment: Cannot find any method like `isPostback` in `ResponseStateManager` class,very strange. I am importing the following in my class `import javax.faces.render.ResponseStateManager;`. Hope this is correct. Thanks

Comment: forget it, method has been added in JSF 1.2, same as with the `VIEW_STATE_PARAM` (used to recognize the post-back). Workaround it setting a name to your forms and checking the submitted URL: if two subsequent request from the same user (session) arrive, the one that has the `formId` as a request parameter identifies a post-back.

Comment: I understand, these are the short comings of using old JSF 1.1 BTW do you have any example of workaround you mentioned? And how to check same user session?. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14269/discussion-between-alonso-dominguez-and-polappan)